# Center ItemizedOverlayItem to screen Center

Tags: java, android, dictionary, overlay

I have a MapView and instatiate an ItemizedOverlayItem in the onCreate() method.
My problem is, that I want to center it to the screen instead of a GeoPoint on the map.
Is there a way to do this?
Also, is there a way to retrieve the relative MapPosition of the OverlayItem?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Could you go further into this?
I am fairly new to Java, I'm sorry.

Thank you!

Comment: what actually you are looking for?

Comment: I look for a way to center the Overlay object to the screencenter instead of a point on the map.

Answer (score 0):

use the below line to move to center of the map.

```
mapView.animateTo(point);
```

the above point will be in center of the mapView.

Comment: The thing is that I would like to use the marker to recieve a location and not bind it to the map.